# HTML `for` doesn't accept an ID of anchor tag

Tags: html

I'm trying to make my HTML more semantic, added IDs to multiple inputs with labels as a part of the same.

However, when I tried to add an ID to an `<a>` tag and referenced the same in `<label>`'s `for` attribute, it still gives me an error.

```html
<div class="form_item">
  <label for="registrationUrl" class="form_label" title="">Registration URL</label>
  <a id="registrationUrl" href="http://reg:3000" data-url="http://reg:3000" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" title="http://reg:3000" class="link link--asBtn-md">
    <span>http://reg:3000</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

The [**w3 Validator**](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea) gives me the following error -
`Error: The value of the for attribute of the label element must be the ID of a non-hidden form control.`

If `<a>` isn't a form control, what should be the semantic way to achieve the same result as shown below?

[image: result image]

Comment: An anchor is not a form control, you can't label every element type.

Comment: "must be the ID of a non-hidden **form control**" a "form control" is either an `<input>`, a `<textarea>`, or a  few others, but `<a>` isn't one.

Comment: @Kaiido comment is on the point, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Basic_native_form_controls

Comment: The `<label>` element does not go with `<a>`. You need to abandon this approach and rethink your design in accordance with proper HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most other answers here are encouraging bad HTML and abusing JavaScript to utilize bad HTML. Instead you should listen to the direction of the w3 validator.

The `<label>` element is not intended for `<a>` elements. **Don't try to force it**, then. Utilize proper HTML. The text between the opening and closing `<a>` tags is intended as the label of the `<a>` element:

```
<a href="http://reg:3000" data-url="http://reg:3000" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" title="http://reg:3000" class="link link--asBtn-md">Registration URL</a>
```

Look at that, proper HTML and no unnecessary JavaScript.

Comment: I don't care. What he wants is invalid HTML.

Answer (score 1):

> The HTML `<label>` element's for attribute is designed to be used with form elements only, such as `<input>`, `<textarea>`, `<select>`, and `<button>`. The for attribute should be used to bind the label to a specific form control through the ID of the control.

> Since the `<a>` tag is not a form control, you cannot use a `<label>` element to associate with it in a semantic HTML way. If you're trying to provide additional information or context about a link, you might consider using other methods.

Certainly, you can achieve the desired click behavior using inline JavaScript within the HTML. Below is a simplified example:

```
<div class="form_item">
  <label class="form_label" onclick="document.getElementById('registrationUrl').click();" style="cursor: pointer;">Registration URL</label>
  <a id="registrationUrl" href="http://reg:3000" target="_blank">
    http://reg:3000
  </a>
</div>
```

> **Note:**
>
> - **Accessibility & Semantics:** While this method provides the desired
>   behavior, it is not a recommended practice in terms of semantic HTML
>   and accessibility. A `<label>` element is not semantically intended to
>   be used with an anchor (`<a>`) element

Comment: You can combine your 2 answers to this post into one.

Comment: @TusharWalzade Sure! :)

Comment: Even though your use of JavaScript will *make* this work, it's still destroying the intent of the HTML elements. The OP should be encouraged rather to utilize proper design and the proper use of HTML elements.

Comment: @reformed You raise a valid point. The proper and semantic use of HTML elements is crucial for maintaining accessibility, usability, and clear structure in web development. Misusing elements can lead to a confusing user experience, particularly for users who rely on screen readers and other assistive technologies.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap them with a valid `form` element that has that URL for the `action` and change the `a` to an `input[type="submit"]` then use CSS to style the button as you wish.
The following is valid HTML:

```css
#registrationUrl {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div class="form_item">
  <form action="http://reg:3000">
    <label for="registrationUrl" class="form_label" title="">Registration URL</label>
    <input type="submit" id="registrationUrl" data-url="http://reg:3000" rel="noopener noreferrer" title="http://reg:3000" class="link link--asBtn-md" value="http://reg:3000">
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here: https://rocketvalidator.com/html-validation/the-value-of-the-for-attribute-of-the-label-element-must-be-the-id-of-a-non-hidden-form-control

we can see that the label `for` **must** refer an `input`:

[image]

Which means that it cannot be an `a`.

So, you can create an `input` `type="text"` instead, design it like an anchor and have a click event to redirect it if you need this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The for attribute within a `<label>` element should be paired with the id attribute of a form control element, like an `<input>`, `<select>`, or `<textarea>`. The intention behind using the for attribute is to create a connection between the label and its corresponding form control. This connection enhances accessibility and improves the user experience, especially for individuals using screen readers and other assistive technologies. You can achieve an identical result using the provided example as well.

```html
<div class="form_item">
    <label class="form_label" title="">
      Registration URL
      <a href="http://reg:3000" data-url="http://reg:3000" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" title="http://reg:3000" class="link link--asBtn-md">
        <span>http://reg:3000</span>
      </a>
    </label>
  </div>
```

Comment: `<label>` elements do not belong with `<a>` elements. Stop encouraging bad HTML practices.

Comment: You are correct that while it is not a recommended practice to use <label> elements with <a> elements in HTML for labeling non-form elements, there might be situations where it is used for general purposes, such as creating clickable labels for non-form content.

In some cases, web developers may use this approach for specific design or layout requirements. However, it's important to be aware of the intended use of HTML elements for better code clarity and accessibility. When using <label> elements for non-form elements like links, it's important to do so judiciously.

Comment: No, there are no such situations. Those are abuses by people who don't understand HTML.

Comment: This will not approach the desire output.